# How can I get g++ to issue a warning when converting int64_t to int?

Tags: c++, linux, x86, g++

I use this command to compile the code below:

```
g++  -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra myfile.cpp
```

I want to get a warning *int64_t is converted into int*. But there is no any warning at all. How can I achieve this?

My g++ version is 4.6.1.

```
//file:myfile.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int64_t yy = 10;
    int size = yy;
    cout << size << endl;
}
```

Comment: What platform ? Maybe ints are 64 bits already ? Try `int32_t size = yy;` ?

Comment: Ubuntu linux 3.0.0-13-generic my OS is 32 bits

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try -Wconversion; due to the large amount of noise this warning tends to produce, it's not part of -Wall

Comment: @jenneb Yeah,It works.And how can I get a warning if the code likes this? size_t yy=10 ;int xx = yy;